# my functions always equal 0 while finding unique and duplicate values in array

Tags: c++

EDIT : Thanks for the helpful comments, I moved my `count_distinct` and my `count_duplicates` inside the while loop where they should have gone from the beginning to make my code look like this

```
unique = count_distinct(data, size); // get result
cout << "There are " << unique << " unique values" << endl;
count = count_duplicates(data, size); // get result 
cout << "There are " << count << " duplicate values" << endl;
```

I went through the debugger and it says that my value `i` is equal to whatever size I input even though I set `i=0` in my function. if i=size then the whole function terminates which causes my unique values to equal 0

```
short count_distinct(short num[], short size)   //Function to return the count of the number of unique/distinct values in the array
{
short i, j, unique=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) //start 1 high to compare to previous numbers
    {
        for(j=0;j<size;j++) //nested for statement which goes through the array to compare with previous numbers
        {
            if (num[i]==num[j]) //compares the numbers to eachother, if they are equal then stop 
            {
                break; // if they are equal then dont count it
            }
        if(i==j)
            unique++;
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
```

*old*

Here is the issue : When I output my unique & duplicate variables they just equal 0.
It might be that my unique and duplicate functions are set up incorrectly.
I have been trying to fix this for a couple hours trying several different things but I don't know what's wrong with the code

This is the debugger error

```
"count & unique = Not found in current context"
```

Here is my code :

```
    using namespace std;

void input_data(short data[], short size);
void display_data (short data[], short size);
short count_distinct(short num[], short size);  // value returning function
short count_duplicates(short num[], short size);  // value returning function

int main()
{   // declare local variables      - do I need to declare more variables??
short size, data[1000], unique, count;  
    unique = count_distinct(data,size);     
    count = count_duplicates(data,size);

cout<<"Enter a size of numbers to process\n";   // display a message to the user about the number of values to store in the array

cin>>size;
while(size>0)
{

    cout<<"Enter the numbers that need to be processed"<<endl;

    input_data(data, size);                     // Call input_data function         - Lets user input elements into array   
    cout<<"There are "<<size<<" values stored in the array."<<endl;

    display_data(data,size);                    // Call display_data function   

    count_distinct(data,size);                  // Call count_distinct function     - Shows unique values       
    cout<<"There are "<<unique<<" unique values"<<endl;

    count_duplicates(data,size);                // Call count_duplicates function   - Shows duplicate values
    cout<<"There are "<<count<<" duplicate values"<<endl;

    cout<<"To run the program again, enter the number of values to\n";
    cout<<"store in the array or 0 to terminate the program";
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cin>>size;

        }

    return 0;
    }

    // Function to input(store) data into the array
    void input_data(short data[], short size){
    short i;    
        for(i=0; i<size;i++)
        {
        cin>>data[i];
        }
    }

    // Function to display the data in the array 
    // print all values on the same line with one space between each number
    void display_data (short data[], short size){
    short i;
    cout<<"Values are : "<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            cout<<data[i]<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
        }

    }


    short count_distinct(short num[], short size)   //Function to return the count of the number of unique/distinct values in the array
    {
    short i, j, unique=0;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) //start 1 high to compare to previous numbers
        {
            for(j=0;j<size;j++) //nested for statement which goes through the array to compare with previous numbers
            {
                if (num[i]==num[j]) //compares the numbers to eachother, if they are equal then stop 
                {
                    break; // if they are equal then dont count it
                }
            if(i==j)
                unique++;
            }
        }
        return unique;
    }


    short count_duplicates(short num[], short size) //Function to return the count of the number of duplicate values in the array
    {
    short i, j, count =0;
        for( i=1;i<size;i++) //start 1 high to compare to previous numbers
        {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++) //nested for statement which goes through the array to compare with previous numbers
            {
                if (num[i]==num[j]) //compares the numbers to eachother
                {
                count++;    // if values are equal they are duplicates
                break;
                }
            }

        }

        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your functions with a debugger? If you have, add that detail to your question, along with the results you observed. The more work you can show, the more likely you'll get answers. (Also the more likely you'll find the problem yourself.)

Comment: Yes I have and nothing is wrong.

Comment: You seem to be calling `unique = count_distinct(data, size);` and `count = count_duplicates(data, size);` before you've collected any data. This will render your program unstable and any results after that are at the mercy of whatever deities you believe in.

Comment: @IsakAngerstig You didn't notice, when using your debugger, that `size` was not set before you went into your `count` functions? I suggest you get a better debugger.

Comment: Sorry I used the debugger on the wrong variable, I just now noticed that. I will set the variable inside of the while loop

Comment: @IsakAngerstig Allow me to suggest that next time you use the debugger to **step through** your failing code, as I advised at the beginning, rather than "using the debugger on a variable", whatever that means. If you had, you would have seen that neither of your failing functions was going into the loops you wrote, and the problem would have become obvious.

Comment: @IsakAngerstig Also allow me to suggest that you turn on warnings in your compiler. Any typical compiler would have complained, and saved you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first semester programming and I'll take your advice and turn on all warnings (I did not know that dev c++ had them turned off)

Comment: The problem with `count_distinct` is utterly trivial. Step through the code with a pencil and paper or with a debugger and look at the values you are comparing.

Comment: Good idea I will try that

Comment: I went through the debugger and it says that my value `i` is equal to whatever size I input even though I set `i=0` in my function. if i=size then the whole function terminates which causes my unique values to equal 0

Answer (score 0):

In main

```
int main()
{ // declare local variables      - do I need to declare more variables??
    short size, data[1000], unique, count;
    unique = count_distinct(data, size);
    count = count_duplicates(data, size);
```

`count_distinct` and `count_duplicates` are called with uninitialized parameters. This invokes undefined behaviour and the program is invalid. Anything that happens after this cannot be trusted.

Most compilers will warn of a mistake like this. Don't ignore compiler warnings. They are often the first line of defense against simple mistakes.

Later

```
    count_distinct(data, size); // Call count_distinct function     - Shows unique values
    cout << "There are " << unique << " unique values" << endl;

    count_duplicates(data, size); // Call count_duplicates function   - Shows duplicate values
    cout << "There are " << count << " duplicate values" << endl;
```

`count_distinct` and `count_duplicates` are called again, but their results are not stored, resulting in printing out whatever invalid results came out of the previous calls.

To fix:

```
int main()
{ // declare local variables      - do I need to declare more variables??
    short size, data[1000], unique, count;
    //unique = count_distinct(data, size); remove this
    //count = count_duplicates(data, size); remove this
```

and

```
    unique = count_distinct(data, size); // get result
    cout << "There are " << unique << " unique values" << endl;
    count = count_duplicates(data, size); // get result 
    cout << "There are " << count << " duplicate values" << endl;
```

`count_distinct` does not work correctly, stepping through your program with a debugger will help you see the mistake, and I also question the need for the `while (size > 0)` loop.